# How to get the data from MysqlDataReader in C# into a .html file

Tags: html, asp.net, mysql

I have created an Empty website in Visual studio 2012.
I have created a class for MySQL data connection where i have written code for establishing connection and query string..
Then there is index.html file in which I have to display database table data.
How to do this?

Please provide a sample for above scenario.

Comment: can you please privide what you have done yet?!

Comment: You could rephrase the question to "How do I create a web site with ASP.NET"?

Comment: Take a step back, do an APS.Net MVC tutorial